# Can I install Google Chrome?

Tags: chromium, google-chrome

I'm a user with rpi3. I'm wondering if I can install Google chrome on my rpi. Can I install it?

Answer (score 2):

Im afraid not. But you can use Chromium, which google chrome is derived. Having said that they are not the same thing. Also the Chromium browser in the rpi repository has been tweaked for the pi, to make it run as good as it can.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```